# Java Array : ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

I have stored bundle of integer values into an ArrayList. However, there are a lot of same duplicate values stored into ArrayList. How can I compare each of every element so that I could only get the different values in ArrayList and store the different values to another ArrayList? As shown as below, I only need values of 36, 33, 31 & 29.

How if I have such output : 36,36,36,35,35,34,33,35,30...?
I need to store values of 36,35,34,33,35,30...into another ArrayList.

**Output from my code:**

```
Battery Array Element : 36
Battery Array Element : 36
Battery Array Element : 36
Battery Array Element : 36
Battery Array Element : 36
Battery Array Element : 36
Battery Array Element : 36
Battery Array Element : 36
Battery Array Element : 33
Battery Array Element : 33
Battery Array Element : 33
Battery Array Element : 33
Battery Array Element : 33
Battery Array Element : 33
Battery Array Element : 33
Battery Array Element : 33
Battery Array Element : 33
Battery Array Element : 31
Battery Array Element : 31
Battery Array Element : 31
Battery Array Element : 31
Battery Array Element : 31
Battery Array Element : 31
Battery Array Element : 31
Battery Array Element : 31
Battery Array Element : 31
Battery Array Element : 31
Battery Array Element : 29
Battery Array Element : 29
Battery Array Element : 29
Battery Array Element : 29
Battery Array Element : 29
Battery Array Element : 29
Battery Array Element : 29
Battery Array Element : 29
```

Comment: And while you're at it, read the Java collections tutorial, which explains the various kinds of collections, what they allows doing, and when to choose one over another. ArrayList is only One of those collections. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be achieved using set to remove duplicates and then adding to a array list.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList<Integer> inputList =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Integer> outputList =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
   inputList.add(36);inputList.add(36);inputList.add(36);inputList.add(36);
   inputList.add(37);inputList.add(37);inputList.add(38);
   Set<Integer>hashSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
   for(Integer val:inputList){
       hashSet.add(val);
   }
   for(Integer i:hashSet){
       outputList.add(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need all the loops. Also a TreeSet is not a hashset.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(new HashSet<Integer>(oldList));`

Answer (score -1):

The best way to avoid duplicated value in an ArrayList is to check if the value you want to add is already present :

For example :

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>() ; // should be somewhere in your code
[...]
int value = 36 ; // value you want to add
if (!list.contains(value)) {
    list.add(value) ;
}
```

Comment: If the number of elements is high, this can be terribly inefficient.